# Sampler name will be empty/blank in the second loop in "View Result Tree"

Tags: jmeter

When I execute the script with Loop count = 2

The sampler's names in the first loop will be displayed correctly in the "View Result Tree".

But the names for the same sampler's in the second loop will be empty/blank in the "View Result Tree", please check the screenshot below.

[image]

Comment: How did you define the sampler name? do you have script which update the sampler name?

Comment: I defined the sampler name in the "Name" field in the sampler"HTTP Request", and there is no script that updates the sampler name.

Comment: What's the Name label?

Comment: /api/test/login

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question doesn't provide sufficient level of details in order to be troubleshooted/reproduced.

[image]

- If you're generating your sampler labels dynamically using [JMeter Functions or Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) (like I did in the above demo) - double check their values at every step using [Debug Sampler and View Results Tree listener combination](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-debug-your-apache-jmeter-script), it might be the case they're getting overwritten/emptied somewhere somehow
- Inspect [jmeter.log file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging) for any suspicious entries, if something goes wrong most probably you will be able to figure out the root cause or get the idea from there

Comment: Thank you, the issue was in the label name.
But when I added a dynamic label beside the label name, the label displayed correctly in the second loop

Answer (score 0):

I faced with same issue. The cause of the error is when the name is changed in HTTP Header Manager plugins, sampler names start to come undefined. This is a bug of JMeter.

The solution is very simple. If the default value:

> HTTP Header Manager

is assigned to all HTTP Header Manager plugins in Jmx, it will be resolved.